# NonUniqueObjectException when persist object

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, persistence

I am getting **NonUniqueObjectException** when i persist an object using JPA.

The object where i make persisent, have other objects and in some cases the objects have the same id.

Make a merge in object where is already saved in DB is a possibility but i only can make persist at one object (this object have all information)

I can put any annotation on my id to make a merge when this id is already saved in MySQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `entityManager.merge(..)` or leave the `id` field empty. Otherwise hibernate will check if an entity exists in the database with the same id and will fail if it finds one.

Comment: I had try to use entityManager.merge but i get an error because the hibernate dont have one of my object with a specified id. I dont know the reason for this because in that point i didnt save nothing in my DB and it's normal hibernate cannot find ir

Comment: I change my cascade type to merge and know is working, thanks to help me solve my problem